# The Rook's Hassle

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Long ago, the Black rook was trapped, stuck on c4, sapped and sacked. Let us unwind its snarly woes, and stop the clock. Turn back the flow, find out how long ago, to the original dock.

**How many moves ago did the Black rook move to c4?**

Thomas Volet & Joost de Heer, Probleemblad 01/2002

[image]

P.S.: Sorry about last time!

Comment: Now this is significantly tougher than the previous problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a complete answer, but I figured I'd post a partial answer here in case someone else feels motivated to continue where I left off. This is one of the most challenging and fun problems I've worked on in a while, so thanks to Rewan for posting it.

The key to this puzzle is the positions of the pawns. Only a single white piece (a pawn) has been taken, while 4 black pieces (a pawn, knight, bishop, and rook) have been taken. Yet looking at the pawns, 4 black pawns are *under* the white pawns.

How did the white pawns get there? The pawn at f2 has never been moved, which means the pawns in files a-e must be from those files (not from further right). We conclude based on which pieces have been taken that white pawns a and b swapped files, as did d and e, accounting for all 4 captured black pieces.

But wait! One of the captured black pieces is a pawn, which must be the one originally at g7 (again, the pawns at c7, f7, and h7 have not moved, and there is no way for the g7 to have moved far enough to the left to be one of the 4 lower black pawns without capturing more pieces than are possible). The only explanation is that the pawn at g7 reached the bottom of the board, got promoted, moved into one of the files a-e, and then got eaten by a white pawn. Importantly, not a single other black pawn ever changed files (there are not enough captured white pieces for a black pawn to move left and then right).

Now that we've established what happened to black's pieces, we can go into specifics about how the pawns got intertwined. Look first at the pawns in files d and e. There is only one possible order of events to get them into that position:

1. Black pawn d moves all the way to its current position (d3).
2. White pawn e moves to e3, then captures something at d4.
3. Black pawn e moves down to e2.
4. White pawn d captures at e3.

Before this maneuver, which we'll call P_de (for Pawn d-e swap), the black king could not have moved to c3, since that would've been check. Therefore, the order of events must be P_de, then Kc3.

Next look at the pawns in files a and b (we'll get to the black rook eventually, I swear). We'll call this maneuver P_ab. The only possible movement order is:

1. Black pawn a moves down to a5
2. White pawn b captures at a6
3. Black pawn b moves down to b4
4. White pawn a captures at b5, then moves up to b6

The white pawn at c5 obviously moved there before the Rc4. So we now have Rc4 surrounded by c5, P_ab, P_de, and Kc3. One or more of these events must have happened after Rc4 in order for the rook to get in there.

Rb5 (the white rook) helps us put things in order. It must have happened after P_ab (that sequence is not possible with the white rook in the way) but before c5 (the rook had to get in there somehow). Hence, P_ab comes before c5, and thus also before Rc4. And Kc3 is clearly after c5 as well (otherwise it blocks the pawn).

```
Known order: P_ab, Rb5, c5, Rc4, Kc3
```

How do we know where Rc4 is chronologically? Because it must be after c5 (it blocks the pawn), and since we already established that P_de is before Kc3, that means that by the time Kc3 happens, P_ab, c5, Kc3, and P_de have all concluded, leaving the black rook with no path into or out of c4. As of yet, we still don't have enough information to definitively say when P_de happened in the above sequence (in the board state below, I assume P_de precedes Rc4, but I never prove it one way or the other).

The rest of this analysis will focus on how to get all the remaining pieces into the triangle in the lower-left corner bounded by the diagonal of white pawns, which I'll call the Bermuda Triangle (since who knows what's going on there).

Ka4 must come after P_ab (it blocks the white pawns otherwise), which means it has to come either before Rb5 (entering the Triangle via b5) or at the latest before Kc3 (entering the Triangle via b3, which it can't do with the king on c3).

Next question: how did the king get to c3? We've already established that P_de, P_ab, Rb5, c5, and Rc4 had all already happened by this point, which means the king's only entrance point to the Triangle is via f1. Thus, Qd2, Be1, and Rc1 all succeed Kc3.

In order to reach e1, the white bishop must pass through d2, which would check the black king if it was on c3. The black king cannot retreat due to the white king on a4 and the black rook above it. The black king must therefore be on c2 at the time, which in turn requires the black bishop to pass through b1. The white queen and white rook must enter the lower left before Be1, but neither can be in their final positions while the king is on c2. This requires a lot of maneuvering that I'll just call the Shuffle for now.

```
Known order: P_ab, Rb5, c5, Rc4, Shuffle(Kc3, Qb1, Rc1, Bc2, Qd2, Be1)
```

The two white knights must move to their final positions after Kc3, since they threaten c2 and d1, which the black king must pass through. However, this poses a problem, since by the end of Kc3, the Bermuda Triangle is completely isolated other than along the bottom row, which the knights can't pass through. One possibility is that during the Shuffle, when the black king is on d1, the white knight that ends on b2 is on c4 (the black rook must not be on c4 yet) and the one that ends on a1 is on b3. Then Kc2 Nb2 Rc4 [white moves] Kc3 Na1.

I won't attempt to continue past this point, as it relies on choreographing every movement that happens during the Shuffle and making sure each piece slots into its final place. I got out a chessboard and tried fiddling with some pieces, but there were too many options that I couldn't narrow down. Assuming the question is well-posed, there must be only a single sequence of moves that ends up in the pictured position after Rc4, but I don't know a good method to find it.

To finish, let me post a picture of approximately what my logic indicates the board looks like when the rook is about to take its final position:

[image]

The black king, white rook, and white queen all enter the Bermuda Triangle from the bottom-right, while the white knights, black bishop, and black queen can all enter via c4 before the black rook moves there. If anyone wants to take a stab at reconstructing the puzzle image starting at this point, be my guest. Or if I made any mistaken assumptions, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I was wrong, it is doable.

> 28 moves.

Solution, without spoilers.

It is easy enough to see that there are 4 black pawns under white ones. Therefore, there had to be 4 captures. White is missing a pawn, black is missing 3 pieces and a pawn which had to be promoted and taken by remaining white pawns. If white pawn promoted then that promoted figure is on the board now and the original fell on h2 - so there couldn't be one extra white piece anywhere that black took during "rook packing".

Out of all pawns, c5 pawn had to move there after a and b pawns did otherwise we couldn't squeeze the b5 rook in; and the d4 pawn had to come from e3.
Could the last moves include de3, Qd2? Obviously not, because how would you get bishop on e1?

Therefore, there were no captures in the last moves - only figures moving around.

So, what was the last move? We are not given whether it is black or white to move.

First, it is white to move now and black had to just move something - obviously bishop or queen as nothing else could have moved. Queen and bishop couldn't have taken a figure, therefore, something had to move to uncover check and either of these moved to block it. What could that be? Only Bd1->c2 preceded by Nc2->Na1. The only previous black move would be Na1->Nb3.
The option is Bb3->Ba1 but black wouldn't have a move, while Na1->Nc2 would have black in check during white's move. The remaining move was h2->h3. Black required Nb3->Na1, but after Qa1->b1 there is no possible black move left.

So, it is black to move.

Previous move was white's. I will write moves in reverse. For example, move Nd1->b2 would be written as Nd1 (= knight N jumped *from* d1 to its next square b2, but destination is obvious).

Move Nd1 is impossible, black king would be in check, and h2->h3 reverts to the case above. So it was 1. Rd1 Qc1 (Nc1 would have white in check during black's move), then (or rather before) 2. Rd2; which means that rook doesn't move until black king does (bishop cannot move to unpin).

EDIT: Here I made a huge mistake, thinking one move is impossible - but isn't. Thanks Ventifacts for showing me the option.

We see that B3 and B4 are blocked by white king which cannot move until black king does, C4 has the walled-in rook, D4,3,2 are covered by pawns and the white rook+bishop, B2 has a knight that cannot move until black king does.
But it IS possible that some time ago, rook was on D1, king was on C2, then rook moved to D2, then king went to the final C3. So, C2 is not an impossible square for king to reverse-move to.

Anyway, the position is now:

https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/1nkpP2P/BNbRpP2/NQq1B3_w_-_-_0_1
There are two options:
2. ... Qd1 3.Qc1 Bb1 4. Nc2 Na1 5. Bb3 - no black move. (Na3 doesn't work, black would be in check)
So,
2. ... Bd1 3. Nc2 Na1 4. Na3 and now either Nb3 or Nc2.

This starts branching quite a bit, so before jumping in brute-force solving the past, what do we want?

The general idea is to get king to c2, rook to d1 and white to move. Rook then moves to d2, forcing king to move to c3, reaching its final square.
Where are the other figures? White bishop is on a2, the only square not attacking c2. Black bishop is then on b1. White knight is on b3 or c1. Because we cannot switch black and white knight - a2-c1-b3-a1-c2-a3-b1 chain is linear (king and rook are stopping c3, d2), white knight needs to be on b3 and black on c1. This leaves queens on a1 and a3.
https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/QN1pP3/BNk1pP1P/qbnRB3_w_-_-_0_1

This has the following few next moves (now in forward!): Rd2 Kc3; h3 Bc2; Bb1...

The previous move had to be Rc3->Rc4 as the only black move - so now we have our last rook move. Checking possible previous moves we get Nd2->Nb3... and a ton of other moves that could have been before (either knights get out via d2, or black rook moves to c3 to let both light square bishops out, dark square bishop can go to d2 letting rook out etc etc.
So, now we are solving from two directions. The final move before rook move is:
https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/Kp1P4/QNrpP3/BNk1pP1P/qbnRB3_w_-_-_0_1
with continuation 0 Rc4; 1. Rd2 Kc3; 2. h3 Bc2; 3. Bb1 Bd1  (https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/QNkpP2P/1N1RpP2/qBnbB3_w_-_-_0_1)

The final position we have so far managed to reconstruct is
https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/N1kpP2P/BN1RpP2/nQqbB3_w_-_-_0_1
(with 4.5 moves from the final)

We need to get those two positions together, starting from either end.

Going forward, one way is 4.Bc2 Qb1 5. Na1 Nb3 6.Qa2 Nc1 7. Bb3 Qc2 8. Qa2 Qb1 9. Nc2 Qa1 10. Qa3 Qb1
We are here:
https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/QBkpP2P/1NNRpP2/1qnbB3_w_-_-_0_1

And from the back, we can attempt similar:
4. ... Nc2 5. Bb3 Na1 6. Qa2 Qb2 7. Bc2 Nb3 8. Qa1 Nc1 9. Bb3 Qc2 10. Qa2 Qb1 11. Nc2 Qa1 12. Qa3 Qb1 ... and we reached that position of the "going forward".

**TLDR: Moves for the final solution:**

We start here:
https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/Kp1P4/QNrpP3/BNk1pP1P/qbnRB3_w_-_-_0_1
And the moves are:
0 Rc4; 1. Rd2 Kc3; 2. h3 Bc2; 3. Bb1 Bd1; 4. Bc2 Qb1; 5. Na1 Nb3; 6.Qa2 Nc1; 7. Bb3 Qc2; 8. Qa3 Qb1; 9. Nc2 Qa1; 10. Qa2 Qb1;
(https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/1BkpP2P/QNNRpP2/1qnbB3_w_-_-_0_1)
11. Na3 Qc2; 12. Qa1 Na2; 13. Qb1 Qc1; 14. Qa1 Qb1; 15. Bc2 Nc1; 16. Qa2 Nb3; 17. Qa1 Qc1; 18. Qa2 Na1; 19. Bb3 Qc2; 20. Qb1 Qc1;
(https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/NBkpP2P/1N1RpP2/nQqbB3_w_-_-_0_1)
21. Qa2 Nc2; 22. Qa1 Qb1; 23. Ba2 Qc1; 24. Qb1 Na1; 25. Nc2 Nb3; 26. Na1 Bc2; 27. Rd1 Qd2; 28. Rc1 - and, with it, finally, the "starting" position
(https://lichess.org/editor/8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/1nkpP2P/BNbqpP2/NQR1B3_w_-_-_0_1)

Full Move Sequence: 8/2p2p1p/PP6/pRP5/KprP4/QN1pP3/BNk1pP1P/qbnRB3 0... Rc3-c4 1. Rd2+ Kc3 2. h3 Bc2 3. Bb1 Bd1 4. Bc2 Qb1 5. Na1+ Nb3 6. Qa2 Nc1 7. Bb3 Qc2 8. Qa3 Qb1 9. Nc2 Qa1 10. Qa2 Qb1 11. Na3 Qc2 12. Qa1 Na2 13. Qb1 Qc1 14. Qa1 Qb1 15. Bc2 Nc1 16. Qa2 Nb3 17. Qa1 Qc1 18. Qa2 Na1 19. Bb3 Qc2 20. Qb1 Qc1 21. Qa2 Nc2 22. Qa1 Qb1 23. Ba2 Qc1 24. Qb1 Na1+ 25. Nc2 Nb3 26. Na1 Bc2 27. Rd1+ Qd2 28. Rc1

Comment: I do assure there is indeed a solution to unshuffling everything.

Comment: From your position in the last paragraph with the rook at d2, if you could shuffle the empty spaces to c2 and d1 (and you moved the white queen and white knight so they weren't threatening c2), couldn't you go Kc2 Rd1 [black moves] Bd2 [black moves] Rh1? Admittedly, the problem is finding black pieces that can move during those bracketed turns. Placing the black knight at b2 seems promising at first, but then where do we put the black bishop? a2 must be taken by the white bishop to prevent check when the king moves to c2, and the black bishop can't be at b3 without checking the white king...

Comment: @VentifactsandYardangs Yup, you are right. I forgot about the possibility that the rook just moved to d2 to give check and so the king moved to the final square.

Comment: @ZizyArcher Wonderful! You've figured out the bulk of the legwork. However, you still have several more moves to shave off to reach the final answer.